# Boolean do not function while trying to make a mold

Tags: modifiers, objects, edit-mode

I am trying to create a mold by doing a boolean from a Nike sneakers. My goal is to then print the mold in 3D later on.

The problem is that the boolean don't work (and the model I took is empty).

Do you have any idea how I can fix that the more efficiently?

[image]

Comment: please provide blend file...but you can try to change between fast and exact. One works.

Comment: Thanks! that worked, it's not the best practice but your solution worked. Thank so much

Comment: you are welcome. Happy, i could help you.